# Calculus two Series

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hi! I ave been spending a lot of time on this Calc2 online homework problem and Im not sure where I am going wrong. I was pretty sure that the sum of the telescoping series was the first term because all of the other terms in the series would cancel each other out, but my answer was wrong and I do not understand why. If anyone has time to help explain the solution to this problem it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

Write $$\frac1{n(n-1)}=\frac{n-(n-1)}{n(n-1)}=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n$$

Observe that on summation up to $N$, the survivor is

$\displaystyle\frac1{7-1}-\frac17+\frac17-\frac18+\cdots+\frac1{N-2}-\frac1{N-1}+\frac1{N-1}-\frac1N=\frac16-\frac1N$

Now, set $N\to\infty$